# "Funnel" or "perspective" scaling?

Tags: transforms

Say I have a square and I want to make it into a trapezoid, I then scale down one of it's sides right?

[image]

Now what if instead of a square I have a very complex square-like object with lots of subdivisions? Is there any way to perform a similar operation? The one that will change the overall shape of the complex square-like object into a trapezoid-like object?

[image]

In Photoshop, when usint freeform transform tool this type of scaling is called "Perspective".

Comment: In your illustration of the transformation of the complex shape, I don't see a trapezoidal transformation; rather, it looks to me like the complex object appears to have undergone a scaling down on the entire top-to-bottom axis, and a scaling up on the entire right-to-left axix.

Comment: dude, add the lion into Photoshot, press Ctrl+T and then right click and choose "Perspective". Then scale down the bottom side like in my first picture (only reverse) and u will get this shape. My example is a bad one I agree.

Comment: Blender is not a photo editing software nor some 2D graphics tool, if you want to transform something you select the corresponding geometry and modify it. In this case I'd select the top edge of the square and scale it down.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos unless you know 100% that Blender cannot do what I need it to do (which your answer does not imply), I can see no point in your answer. Just a waste of memmory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a [Lattice](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/lattice.html?highlight=lattice%20modifier) and position it so that it encloses the object you want to deform.

Select the object to be deformed and add a [Lattice Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/lattice.html?highlight=lattice%20modifier) to it.

On the modifier select the lattice that will be used.

[image]

Select the lattice, enter edit mode and change its shape by moving some vertices, the object will deform along with it.

[image]

Comment: Selecting your answer as an "answer" because I never bother to add giffs :).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what I needed was Mesh Deform modifier.

[image]

https://docs.blender.org/manual/ko/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/mesh_deform.html